# Where are the image and sound files inside XCode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, unity-game-engine

Are the images and sound files that are used inside the Unity IDE somehow compiled into libiPhone-lib.a inside XCode? I'm looking for a way to access the audio files and images inside XCode/Objective-C. As far as I can tell by looking at the exported XCode project, there are no sound files or other resources anywhere to be seen

Answer (score 1):

They are compiled into the lib as a byte code which is then interpreted at runtime. Disclosure of this would destroy Unity's business model, as everyone would make corrections into unity-produced code. It is more easy for them to interpret bytecode rather than translating it into human-readable language like C or objective-c.

The answer is: yes, they are compiled into lib.

If you want to access them from objective-c layer, you have to add them to project again in a usual xCode way ,so their data will be doubled in the project.